# Unique combinations of 3 values from a very large value arrays without any repetition

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, data-structures

I have to make combination of 3 unique values on every request. From given arrays:

```
1.) Attributes : 70 count
2.) Object : 1000 Count
3.) Object : 1000 Count
```

Objects in 2 and 3 are same and combination results expected would be like:

```
[attr-1, Obj-10, Obj-40]
[attr-21, Obj-54, Obj-987]
[attr-69, Obj-89, Obj-765]
and so on.
```

**Note:**

1. DB is MySql
2. PHP files to execute requests.
3. Once a combination is generated, it can't come next time.

Now, I thought of a solution by building a 2D array with Attributes as Cols and Objects are Rows.

```
        attr-1 | attr-2 | attr-3 | attr-4   
Obj-1                   
Obj-2                   
Obj-3                   
Obj-4
```

And traversing this array along with filling the cell which is done.
But this misses combinations.

One main problem is that if I use simple DB query to get unique combinations
and then store that are generated. Then after a period of time when the done
combinations size will increase and then generating a new unique combination 
then verifying that it has been already generated will take a lot of time.

I am thinking to build a pattern that will be followed for response but the user will have an illusion that a unique combination is generated.

**So conclusion is that, I need:**

1. A formula that generates unique combinations and I can not use that combination which is already been generated and played.
2. above 1 is difficult as saving played combinations will be hard after sometime, so make a pattern in which we'll play the combinations and user will have illusion of randomly generated combination.

Comment: _“Once a combination is generated, it can't come next time”_ – that is quite vague, you need to specify “next time” more exactly. Does this have to be unique “per request”, no matter who makes it? Or just per user? For how long a time, does it still have to be “unique” if the next request is made only in a month from now?

Comment: I think that rather than checking for uniqueness against previous combinations, this would be easier if you created all combinations upfront, and “shuffled” them once. Then each time you take the “next” combination out of that shuffled data set. Once all combinations have been cycled through, you start by shuffling the whole data set again.

Comment: But you see 70x1000x1000 will be big thing to store and literate. Its for a mobile app.

Comment: Granted, that is a lot of data (although “mobile” doesn’t matter here, because data will be stored server-side). But a solution that calculates a random combination, and then checks this against all previous combinations (which you would have to store for this to work anyway) will not do much better once you reach a certain number of already used combinations. So I see two possible ways: Either find an algorithm that only _emulates_ randomness, by _calculating_ combinations, maybe based on a random ”seed” value (difficult), […]

Comment: […] or only save the last x combinations used, and hope that the user will not realize that there’s a “duplicate” after seeing, say, two or three dozen combinations anyway … so that you only have to check for a duplicate against those last x combinations when randomly finding a new one, and when a new combination is found and stored, the “oldest” of those x previously saved ones gets deleted again.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks a lot for taking time to suggest solutions, first of all sorry for the late reply. Just got busy with my JOB, Today, I just took out my code and started building again. For the time being I am thinking, not to save combinations for now, generating randoms from 70x1000x1000, chances are a user will not get duplicate values instantly (I'll will add check for previous 10 combinations played). and if the app idea worked, we can think of this in 2nd phase of the app.